# Why does head not cancel subscription

Tags: scala, rx-java

Let's say you have the following `Observable` in `rxjava-scala-0.18.4`

```
@volatile var dorun = true
var subscriber: Subscriber[String] = null
val myObs = Observable { obs: Subscriber[String] =>
  subscriber = obs
  Subscription { println("unsubscribed"); dorun = false }
}

val sub = myObs.head.subscribe(println(_))

assertTrue(dorun)

subscriber.onNext("hello")
Thread.sleep(500)
assertFalse(dorun)

subscriber.onNext("world")
Thread.sleep(500)
assertFalse(dorun)
```

The second assertion fails, which means that `head` does not unsubscriby. Is my understanding of Observables wrong or should `head` unsubscribe after the first element got emitted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at your `subscribe()` method: you loop until `run` is set to `false`, but the only way for that to happen would be to close the subscription.  The problem is that **nobody has the subscription yet:**  the loop keeps you from returning.  The `head` operator can't terminate the underlying subscription after the first item is delivered *because it hasn't finished subscribing yet*.  Thus, you just keep looping forever.

One solution would be to move your loop into an action scheduled on `Schedulers.trampoline()`.  Then the events would be delivered some time after returning from `subscribe()`.

Additionally, in your `subscribe()` method, it seems you need to add the new subscription object to the `Subscriber` that gets passed in, like so:

```
val myObs = Observable {
    obs: rx.lang.scala.Subscriber[String] =>
        ...

        obs.add(
            Subscription {
                dorun = false
                println("unsubscribed")
            }
        )
}
```

Comment: Although you are right for the example I posted, the problem persists even if I run the loop in a seperate Thread. See edited question

Comment: Your modified example seems nondeterministic.  Nothing stops the new thread from running through the loop several times before the call to `subscribe()` returns.  You're at the mercy of the thread scheduler.  Does the second thread eventually terminate?  The only thing the contract guarantees is that `onNext()` will be called at most once.  Also, I don't know Scala very well--might it be necessary to somehow mark `dorun` as volatile?

Comment: I rewrote the code to be in a single Thread with plenty of time for everything to settel down. It still does not cancel the subscription.

Comment: I'm not sure how closures work with mutable variables in Scala, so let's try replacing your `dorun` local with a `BooleanSubscription` object and returning that as the subscription.  You can use its `isUnsubscribed` method in place of `dorun`.

Comment: since `dorun` is a field on the enclosing `object` you can set it from anywhere. Never the less, "unsubscribe" should come up in the output.

Comment: OK, I think I found your problem.  Apparently, in your `subscribe()` method, you need to `add()` the subscription to the `Subscriber` that was passed in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55382/discussion-between-blank-chisui-and-mike-strobel).

Comment: Unfortunately, StackOverflow Chat is blocked at my office.